# How to convert null to empty String in Ionic React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, frontend

I want to submit a form in an API endpoint. I have many inputs, but here I'm including only the input which causes the error: 'phone' input, which is not required.
When I don't fill 'phone' input,  I get this error:

```
{validation_messages: {phone: {stringLengthInvalid: "Invalid type given. String expected"},…},…}
detail: "Failed Validation"
status: 422
title: "Unprocessable Entity"
```

**In Backend, it accepts String or empty String ''.**
Error:
{
"phone": null,
}
Correct:
{
"phone": ""
}

My component:

```
const UpdateData: React.FC = () => {
  const {
    phone,
    setPhone,
  } = React.useContext(MyContext);

  
  const updateContact = () => {
    const data = {
   
      phone: phone,
     
    };

    axios
      .put("/xx/update", data)
      .then((response) => {
        setPhone(response.data.phone);
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setMessage("Sth went wrong!");
        setIserror(true);
      });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <IonPage className="ion-page" id="main-content">
        <IonContent className="ion-padding">
          <IonGrid>
                <form className="ion-padding">
 
                  <IonItem>
                    <IonLabel position="floating">Phone</IonLabel>
                    <IonInput
                      placeholder="Example: 0333-12345678"
                      value={phone}
                      onIonChange={(e) => setPhone(e.detail.value)}
                    ></IonInput>
                  </IonItem>

                  <IonButton
                    className="ion-text-center btn-warning"
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      updateContact();
                      history.goBack();
                    }}
                  >
                    Save
                  </IonButton>
                </form>
          </IonGrid>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default UpdateData;
```

In 'MyContext' I have set states for my input:

```
const [phone, setPhone] = useState<string>("");
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The error says `stringLengthInvalid`, not necessarily that it was a `null` ... Maybe your backend doesn't accept empty string. Have you confirmed this?

Comment: Yes it accepts empty strings, `const data = {
   
      phone: phone || "",    };` solves the issue but I still see null value for just 1 second, when the component containing my updated data is rendered.  The field shows null just for 1 second and then it disappears. It is supposed to show nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
const data = {
   
      phone: phone || "",
     
    };
```

Comment: I was about to use ternary expressions such as: `phone===null ? " " : phone`, but your way is much better. Thank you, it works. The only issue is that when the empty field is rendered in another component, for just 1 second I can see null in the field and then it disappears. I don't want to see null at all. Do you know how to avoid this? I hope you understood what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, it will set a default value to Phone.

```
const {
    phone = "",
    setPhone,
  } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
```

Comment: I have set the default value in MyContext. Do I need to add a default value inside the component too?

Answer (score 0):

Your backend should work fine with the default value.

```
    const data = {

          phone: phone || " ",
 
    };
```

To remove null entirely try putting a space between the quotes.

Comment: In this case, I get the error: Internal Server Error. `const data = {

          phone: phone || " ",
 
    };` This works but for just 1 second it renders null when I open the component, and then it dissappears. I don't want to see null at all. That's the issue I'm facing now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this where you evaluate

```
setPhone(e.detail.value ? e.detail.value : "")
```